# How do I create checkboxes that correspond to embedded links

Tags: html

Help me create checkboxes with embedded links

Everything

```html
<body style="text-align: left;">
  <h1>Select which delimiter you want to use.</h1>
  <big>Select either TSV or CSV: </big><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="acs" value="CSV">CSV<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="acs" value="TSV">TSV<br>
  <p>
    <input type="button" onclick='printChecked()' value="Print Selected Items" /input>
  </p>
</body>
```

It prints checkboxes with no attached links.

Comment: What do you mean by *"checkboxes with embedded links"*? What should happend when the checkbox is checked? What's the real question here?

Comment: what is the expected outcome after clicking/ticking a checkbox?

Comment: Your function `printChecked()` is not defined. It's in that function that you should determine the action to do according to which check box is selected

Comment: Please [edit] your question, it sounds like there's an interesting problem to be answered but I can't work out, yet, what you're asking for. What's an 'embedded link,' and what do they have to do with your checkboxes? What does the user do, and what should happen? *Please*: read the "*[ask]*" guidance, and then we can offer useful help.

Answer (score 0):

Following code contains what you are looking for

```js
function printChecked(){
   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("acs");
   var list = document.getElementById("chckValues");
   list.innerHTML = "";
   for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
    if(checkboxes[i].checked == true){
     var listentry = document.createElement('li');
     var link = document.createElement('a');
     link.href = '#' + checkboxes[i].id
     link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(checkboxes[i].value));
  listentry.appendChild(link);
  list.appendChild(listentry);
     }
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Select which delimiter you want to use.</h1>
<big>Select either TSV or CSV: </big><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="acs1" name="acs" value="CSV">CSV<br> 
<input type="checkbox" id="acs2" name="acs" value="TSV">TSV<br>
<p>
<input type="button" onclick='printChecked()' value="Print Selected Items" /input>
</p>
<ol id="chckValues"></ol>
```